# how to write a recursive function for my multilevel list and apply my logic of rowspan and colspan within it

Tags: c#, recursion

This is my code which has a list of table. consisting
headers,subheaders and subsubheaders. i have two fields rowspan and
colspan for each of my headers,subheaders and subsubheaders which i
need to set using a recursive function. In the below code i have
written the logic for setting rowspan and colspan in two different
functions rowspan() and colspan(). And have used them in my main
function.But for each of my headers and subheaders i have to set them
separately. How can i perform it by using a recursive function? kindly help.
[this is the table for which iam setting rowspan and colspan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Aux.png)

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication3 {
     public class Table
     {
       public  List<tableheader> headers {get; set;} 

         public class tableheader
         {
             public string title;
             public List<tableheader> subheaders = new List<tableheader>();
             public int rowspan;
             public int colspan;
             public int order;

         }
     }
     }
     class Program
     {
         static int level;
         static int max;
         static int count;

         public static int rowspan(int level)
         {
             int x;
             if (count!=0)
             {
               x=1;
             }
             else
             {
                x =( max - level) + 1;
             }
             return x;
         }

         public static int colspan()
         {
             int y = 1;
             if ( count != 0)
             {

                 y=count;
             }
             return y;

         }

         public static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             level = 0;
             Table table=new Table();
             table.headers=new List<Table.tableheader>();

              level++;

             Table.tableheader A = new Table.tableheader();
                 A.title = "A";
                 A.order=level;


               Table.tableheader B = new Table.tableheader();
                 B.title = "B";
                 B.order=level;


               Table.tableheader C = new Table.tableheader();
                 C.title = "C";
                 C.order=level;

                 level++;

                B.subheaders = new List<Table.tableheader>();

                Table.tableheader B1 = new Table.tableheader() {title="B1" ,order=level};
               Table.tableheader B2 = new Table.tableheader() {title ="B2",order=level };
                B.subheaders.Add(B1);
                B.subheaders.Add(B2);

                C.subheaders = new List<Table.tableheader>();
               Table.tableheader C1 = new Table.tableheader() { title = "C1", order = level };
               Table.tableheader C2 = new Table.tableheader() { title = "C2", order = level };
                C.subheaders.Add(C1);
                C.subheaders.Add(C2);

                level++;

                Table.tableheader B21 = new Table.tableheader() { title = "B21", order = level };
                Table.tableheader B22 = new Table.tableheader() { title = "B22", order = level };
                B2.subheaders.Add(B21);
                B2.subheaders.Add(B22);

                table.headers.Add(A);
                table.headers.Add(B);
                table.headers.Add(C);

          max = level;

          count=A.subheaders.Count();
          A.rowspan=rowspan(A.order);
          A.colspan = colspan();

         count=B.subheaders.Count();
         B.rowspan=rowspan(B.order);

         count = B1.subheaders.Count();
         B1.rowspan = rowspan(B1.order);
         B1.colspan = colspan();

         count = B2.subheaders.Count();
         B2.rowspan = rowspan(B2.order);
         B2.colspan = colspan();

         count = B1.rowspan + B2.rowspan;
         B.colspan = colspan();

         count = C.subheaders.Count();
         C.rowspan = rowspan(C.order);
         C.colspan = colspan();

         count = C1.subheaders.Count();
         C1.rowspan = rowspan(C1.order);
         C1.colspan = colspan();

         count = C2.subheaders.Count();
         C2.rowspan = rowspan(C2.order);
         C2.colspan = colspan();

         count = B21.subheaders.Count();
         B21.rowspan = rowspan(B21.order);
         B21.colspan = colspan();

         count = B22.subheaders.Count();
         B22.rowspan = rowspan(B22.order);
         B22.colspan = colspan();

      }             }
```

Comment: where did you got those plenty of '>' at the beginning of each line, the assignments directly?

Comment: code sample @LeiYang

Comment: and don't you want to remove them?

Comment: ya i did..thanks @LeiYang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if code below helps.  Made lots of changes to your original.  I didn't write recursive function but you should be able to figure this out yourself with my updated code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class Table
    {
        public static Tableheader headers { get; set; }
        public static int max;
        public class Tableheader
        {
            public string title;
            public List<Tableheader> subheaders;
            public int rowspan;
            public int colspan;
            public int order;

        }
        public void Add(DataTable data)
        {
            headers = new Tableheader();
            int level = 0;
            AddRecursive(data, headers, "", 0);
        }

        public void AddRecursive(DataTable data, Tableheader headers, string headerName, int level)
        {
            if (level > max) max = level;
            foreach (DataRow row in data.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("parent") == headerName))
            {
                if (headers.subheaders == null) headers.subheaders = new List<Tableheader>();

                Tableheader newHeader = new Tableheader();
                headers.subheaders.Add(newHeader);

                string title = row.Field<string>("title");
                newHeader.title = title;
                AddRecursive(data, newHeader, title, level++);

            }
        }
        public int AddRecursiveSpan(int level, Tableheader header)
        {
            int cols = 0;
            foreach (Tableheader sHeader in header.subheaders)
            {
                if (sHeader.subheaders == null)
                {
                    sHeader.rowspan = max - level + 1;
                    sHeader.colspan = 1;
                    cols += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    sHeader.colspan += AddRecursiveSpan(level + 1, sHeader);
                    sHeader.rowspan = 1;
                    cols += sHeader.colspan;
                }
            }
            return cols;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("title", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("parent", typeof(string));


            dt = new List<DataRow>() {
                 dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A",""}),
                 dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"B",""}),
                 dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"C",""}),
                 dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"B1","B"}),
                 dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"B2","B"}),
                 dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"C1","C"}),
                 dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"C2","C"}),
                 dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"B21","B2"}),
                 dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"B22","B2"})
             }.CopyToDataTable();

            Table table = new Table();
            table.Add(dt);
            int level = 1;
            table.AddRecursiveSpan(level,Table.headers);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. sorry but cannot use this code...i need to have just one recursive function for setting rowspan and colspan. And my list representation was correct no changes in that because i need fields to store their values in my database. just the code below my list representation where i have taken counts for each of my headers that needs to be improved with a recursive function.

Comment: Then simply change headers from string to a class.  Still you need an input table to recursively add items to your classes.

Comment: i just  need a recursive function for my rowspan colspan logic in my code ...rest is meant to be as it is...but how to do with the hep of  recursive function that i dont know....that is the help i want

Comment: updated code isnt meant for rowspan and colspan...i want recursive function for my rowspan and colspan.

Comment: Read the question again and debug my code....u will understand what iam trying to say...And i have updated the question with a picture of my table for which iam setting rowspan and colspan.

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't exactly know what values you needed for the rowspan and colspan.  I thought you could easily modify the code yourself.  I added max into code.  You need a 2nd recursive method to add rowspan and colspan after max is found.  The recursive method would look very similar to the code I posted.

Comment: all i wanted is a recursive function for my rowspan colspan...nothing else..that itself u r telling me to figure out..And the recursive method wont look the same like the one u posted.That should call my header to submit its rowspan and header in return should ask the subheaders to submit theirs.And it should return both colspan and rowspan.